# Break longtable on multirows

Tags: longtable, multirow

Is it possible to break a longtable so that it doesn't split multirows?

For example, this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

Here's some text to screw up spacing :)

\begin{longtable}[l]{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
  \textbf{Decade} & \textbf{Advancements} & \textbf{Works} & \textbf{Summaries}\endhead\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline'

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

produces this:[image: Icky Spacing]

Ideally it would break at the bottom of the previous multirow, so that when it carried over to the next page it wouldn't have that space beneath 'Decade' and the widowed row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can use `\\*` to discourage breaks but the horizontal lines allow them again so automatically avoiding this is a bit tricky.

A manual fix is easy though, just insert `\pagebreak` before the `\multirow` block.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

Here's some text to screw up spacing :)

\begin{longtable}[l]{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
  \textbf{Decade} & \textbf{Advancements} & \textbf{Works} & \textbf{Summaries}\endhead\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline'

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\*\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\*\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\*\hline

\pagebreak
  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\*\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\*\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\*\hline

  \multirow{3}{*}{year - year} & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\cline{2-4}
                  & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```